# Should I include PDF files in my sitemap.xml

Tags: sitemap, pdf

Should I add a direct link to PDF files in my (xml) [sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want them indexed, yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: They might get indexed even if not added into the sitemap. If the website contains a link to them, Google might follow it.

Comment: Of course. But blocking content is not in the scope of this question.